# PowerShell - Accessing root web.config

Tags: web-config, iis-8.5, powershell-5.1

I can't seem to find a good hint on accessing the root web.config, currently in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config.  In my situation, I want to apply a few security settings to cascade down to apps (ex: disable sessionstate/compression) where ideally I'd do this in PowerShell DSC using xWebConfigProperty, or possibly raw PowerShell.  If anyone has a means to retrieve this (have to use the older WebAdministration module), I'd appreciate it (or just verifying I need something more organic like gci path into xml for manipulation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes applied to root web.config using 'MACHINE/WEBROOT'.

You can test with something like:
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT'  -name "mode"  -filter "system.web/sessionState"